# page_load not getting called when redirected to it

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, intuit-partner-platform

In Intuit App Center when the user clicks on my app they are supposed to be sent to www.myweb.com\OpenIdHandler.aspx.

Fiddler shows:

```
GET https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/b7nyqfscsm
302 Found to https://myweb.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx

CONNECT http://myweb.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

CONNECT http://myweb.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

GET https://appcenter.intuit.com/app/b7nyqfscsm
302 Found to https://myweb.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx

CONNECT http://myweb.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

CONNECT http://myweb.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

CONNECT http://myweb.com:443
200 Connection Established ()

GET https://myweb.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx
302 Found to /Default.aspx

GET https://myweb.com/Default.aspx
302 Found to /Login.aspx

GET https://myweb.com/Login.aspx
200 OK (text/html)
```

I have logging turned on page_load in OpenIdHandler.aspx and nothing is getting logged so I know OpenIdHandler.aspx page_load is not getting called.

If I go https://myweb.com/OpenIdHandler.aspx AFTER landing on the login page (but not logging in) all works as expected (it figures out that I am logged in via Intuit App Center/Intuit OpenID).

Question: Why isn't OpenIdHandler.aspx Page_load getting called?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why isn't OpenIdHandler.aspx Page_load getting called?

Comment: If I had to guess, your Forms Authentication login page is Login.aspx and it is bypassing the request for OpenIdHandler.aspx.  Have you tried putting the OpenIdHandler.aspx logic into the Login.aspx page?

Answer (score 2):

From the fiddler output it looks like you are not logged in and OpenIdHandler.aspx is redirecting (via a 302 Found redirect) to Default.aspx, which then redirects you to Login.aspx.

Check your authentication setup, if OpenIdHandler.aspx requires authorization, the redirect will happen before any code on the page gets executed.  It looks like you need to make sure that OpenIdHandler.aspx does not require authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guesses on such a vague question.

The culprit was in Global.asax.cs:

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); //<--------------
    }
```

If you comment that out then all is happy!